# How to query on parquet files using pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pyarrow, fastparquet

I have a parquet file with 35 columns nd i have to check if a specific value is present in a column or not using pyarrow.does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The example from the [dataset](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#filtering-data) docs might be useful:

Something like:

```
dataset = ds.dataset(base / "parquet_dataset", format="parquet")
dataset.to_table(columns=['a'], filter=ds.field('a') >= 7).to_table
```